# Layout Gravity In Part Of Screen

Tags: android, layout

First, sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem in one of my layouts.
I want something like this (**Image on top, and three buttons with Layout Gravity after**)

**Image, click on the link**.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vl8jlw6s5br69c5/StackOverflow%20copia.PNG

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>      
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"  >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top" >

            <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/logo"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:contentDescription="@string/portada_mi"
              android:src="@drawable/sillas"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/llayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llayout1"
        android:gravity="center" >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton1_mi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#e67e22"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/opcion1_mi"
                android:width="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>  


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton2_mi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/boton1_mi"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#e67e22"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/opcion2_mi"
                android:width="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton3_mi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/boton2_mi"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#e67e22"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/opcion3_mi"
                android:width="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" />         


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton4_mi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/boton3_mi"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#e67e22"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:height="50dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/opcion4_mi"
                android:width="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My result with this code is**:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pept7hn08e2zlhp/Screenshot_2014-03-04-17-15-19.png

**Please anyone can help me with an answer or an article of another web.**

Answer (score 0):

For buttons use LinearLayout instead of Relative. And set ur layout orientation as vertical. Probably it ll fix ur problem.